# array output not working from class php

Tags: php, oop

i got error using this code

***Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /home/u448966927/public_html/Myclass.php on line 8***

**Myclass.php**

```
<?php

class yt
{
    public $channels = array
    (
        "music" => array( "id" => 74,"img" => "<img src=../icon/music.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Music", "slug" => "music") ,
        "sports" => array( "id" => 11,"img" => "<img src=../icon/sport.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Sports", "sug" => "sport"),
        "movies" => array( "id" => 45,"img" => "<img src=../icon/movies.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Movies", "sug" => "movie"),
        "gaming" => array( "id" => 85,"img" => "<img src=../icon/game.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Gaming", "sug" => "game"),
        "people" => array( "id" => 56,"img" => "<img src=../icon/people.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "People & Blog", "sug" => "people"),
        "comedy" => array( "id" => 72,"img" => "<img src=../icon/comedy.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Comedy", "sug" => "comedy"),
        "news" => array( "id" => 84,"img" => "<img src=../icon/news.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "News & Politics", "sug" => "news"),
        "animation" => array( "id" => 29,"img" => "<img src=../icon/film.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Film & Animation", "sug" => "animation"),
        "auto-vehicles" => array( "id" => 59,"img" => "<img src=../icon/auto.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Autos & Vehicles", "sug" => "auto-vehicles"),
        "howto" => array( "id" => 68,"img" => "<img src=../icon/howto.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Howto & Style", "sug" => "howto"),
        "science" => array( "id" => 98,"img" => "<img src=../icon/science.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Science & Technology", "sug" => "science")

    );
    public function getChannels(){
        $html = "<li><a href='#' class='current'><img src=../icon/pupolar.png height=18 width=18 />\tPopular</a>";
        ksort(channels);
        foreach (channels as $channel) {
            $html .="<li><a href='channel/".$channel["slug"]."'>now</a>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
};

?>]
```

**INDEX.php**

```
<?php include_once('Myclass.php'); echo getChannels(); ?>
```

Comment: i felt to much dificulity to post this question finaly i host my code another website and give a long link i was trying to post this question from 45 mints

Comment: Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help should help. Especially: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: but please tell me what i do how to creat my question tru error erorror error again and again when i press click on pos question error arise you code is not defined press crtl+k

Comment: @Epodax now my question is correct Thankyou

Comment: You need to create object of class yt like 
`$yt = new yt(); echo $yt->getChannels();`

Also as suggested below you will need to add `$` to channels variable. @MAbidMajeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`channels` doesn't exist and is invalid in your `ksort` and `foreach` (line 22)

Change

```
ksort(channels);
foreach (channels as $channel) {
```

To

```
ksort($this->channels);
foreach ($this->channels as $channel) {
```

As the function `getChannels` is in a class, you need to [instantiate the class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new). In `index.php` add the following;

```
$objYT = new yt;
echo $objYT->getChannels();
```

https://eval.in/415737

Comment: Thank you soo much you and @RiggsFolly solve my problem

Comment: If I solved your problem, why have you accepted another answer? no dig deal, but it looks a little odd for others looking at this question.

Answer (score 1):

Change this piece of code from

```
&lt;?php include_once(&apos;ytcx.php&apos;); echo getChannels(); ?&gt;
```

To

```
<?php 
    include_once('ytcx.php'); 
    $obj = new yt();
    echo $obj->getChannels();
?>
```

I think PHP thinks that `&apos;` is a parameter being passed, the `&` is a by-reference character in PHP and it is just getting confused.

You also need to change

```
public function getChannels(){
        $html = "<li><a href='#' class='current'><img src=../icon/pupolar.png height=18 width=18 />\tPopular</a>";
        ksort($this -> channels);
        foreach ($this -> channels as $channel) {
            $html .="<li><a href='channel/".$channel["slug"]."'>now</a>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

When you are referencing a class property from within a class method, you need the `$this->`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
class yt
{
    public $channels = array
    (
        "music" => array( "id" => 74,"img" => "<img src=../icon/music.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Music", "slug" => "music") ,
        "sports" => array( "id" => 11,"img" => "<img src=../icon/sport.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Sports", "slug" => "sport"),
        "movies" => array( "id" => 45,"img" => "<img src=../icon/movies.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Movies", "slug" => "movie"),
        "gaming" => array( "id" => 85,"img" => "<img src=../icon/game.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Gaming", "slug" => "game"),
        "people" => array( "id" => 56,"img" => "<img src=../icon/people.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "People & Blog", "slug" => "people"),
        "comedy" => array( "id" => 72,"img" => "<img src=../icon/comedy.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Comedy", "slug" => "comedy"),
        "news" => array( "id" => 84,"img" => "<img src=../icon/news.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "News & Politics", "slug" => "news"),
        "animation" => array( "id" => 29,"img" => "<img src=../icon/film.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Film & Animation", "slug" => "animation"),
        "auto-vehicles" => array( "id" => 59,"img" => "<img src=../icon/auto.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Autos & Vehicles", "slug" => "auto-vehicles"),
        "howto" => array( "id" => 68,"img" => "<img src=../icon/howto.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Howto & Style", "slug" => "howto"),
        "science" => array( "id" => 98,"img" => "<img src=../icon/science.png height=18 width=18 />", "name" => "Science & Technology", "slug" => "science")

    );

    public function getChannels(){
        $html = "<li><a href='#' class='current'><img src=../icon/pupolar.png height=18 width=18 />\tPopular</a>";
        ksort($this->channels);
        foreach ($this->channels as $channel) {
            $html .="<li><a href='channel/".$channel["slug"]."'>now</a>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

----- On index.php ---

```
  include_once('Myclass.php'); 
    $yt = new yt;    
    echo $yt->getChannels();
```

Comment: You've missed to use $this-> to access class property and there misspelled slug to sug in some arrays on Myclass.php, On index.php you did not create object to access class method which is getChannels. Thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in the code you have posted.

```
ksort(channels);
foreach (channels as $channel) {
```

The names of variables in PHP start with `$`. When PHP reaches `channels` it thinks it is a constant created using [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). But function [`ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) expects a parameter of type array passed by reference. This is the source of the error.

If you change it to `ksort($channels)` it is still an error because there is no variable `$channels` defined in the current scope. What you probably need is to use the `$channels` property of the current object and that one is always accessed using `$this` (the current object) followed by the `->` (member access operator) and the name of the property you want to access, without `$` (`channels`):

```
ksort($this->channels);
```

The same for the next line:

```
foreach ($this->channels as $channel);
```

You also have a similar problem in `index.php`:

```
<?php include_once('Myclass.php'); echo getChannels();
```

The call to `getChannels()` tries to execute the global function `getChannels()` but it fails because no such function exists. What you want to accomplish is a call to method `getChannels()` of an object of class `yt`. In order to do that you have to create such an object first:

```
<?php
include_once 'Myclass.php';
$obj = new yt();
echo $obj->getChannels();
// That's all
```

And the file `Myclass.php` should look like:

```
<?php

class yt
{
    // ...

    public function getChannels(){
        $html = "<li><a href='#' class='current'><img src=../icon/pupolar.png height=18 width=18 />\tPopular</a>";
        ksort($this->channels);
        foreach ($this->channels as $channel) {
            $html .="<li><a href='channel/".$channel["slug"]."'>now</a>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```